# jquery scrolltop only works with jquery < 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

i'm using the newest version (2.2.1) of readmore.js from http://jedfoster.com and the scrollTop function in my affterToggle only works if i'm using jquery smaller then version 3.0.0. So jquery 2.*.* and 1.*.* works fine.

I googled but i dont find anything special about scrollTop and jquery 3.

```
  $('#text').readmore({
    speed: 75,
    moreLink: '<a href="#">read more</a>',
    lessLink: '<a href="#">close</a>',
    collapsedHeight: 60,
    afterToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {
      if (!expanded) { // The "Close" link was clicked
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top }, 100);
      }
    }
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0djenaxh/5/

Change jquery version to 1 or 2 and it works ... Can anybody tell me why this dont work with jquery 3?

Greetings

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a scrollTop issue, but rather a readmore plugin issue with jQuery 3ish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery scrollTop works fine with all jQuery versions (You can test scrollTop with different jQuery versions here: http://jsfiddle.net/rdayptu8/3/ )

According to your code, the `afterToggle` method in readmore.js does not gets called/involved in the latest version of jQuery. It will definitely be the readmore.js library being not supported by the latest jQuery versions.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification :)